# ¿Cómo hago para insertar las iniciales de los textos de un archivo .txt en el mismo archivo en python?

Tags: python, lista, archivo, texto

Estoy intentando ingresar las iniciales de los textos de un archivo que abrí en python en líneas nuevas de ese mismo archivo, pero me está fallando el código en alguna parte y no logro verlo.

```
file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "ar")

for line in file.readlines():
    words = line.split('')
    character = ''
    for word in words:
        character += word[0]
file.write('\n'+ character)
file.close()
```

Comment: dices que falla pero no nos indicas de que modo. Tienes un error en consola? No tienes el resultado esperado?

Comment: que es ese modo de apertura?

Comment: Debes proporcionar un ejemplo de la entrada y la salida esperada, para comprobar la correción de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Vayamos por partes, en primer lugar el modo que especificas no es válido, si quieres leer y escribir usa `r+`, luego el `split` dará error por no tener un parámetro válido.

```py
file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt","r+")

for line in file.readlines():
    words = line.split()
    character = ''
    for word in words:
        character += word[0]
file.write('\n' + character) 
file.close()
```

Como recomendación, siempre que puedas usa `with` para abrir archivos y así te ahorrarás tener que cerrarlos.

```
with open("/usercode/files/books.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   # instrucciones sobre el archivo
```